# Programmatically add custom meta description via metatag module

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I'm trying to add a custom meta tag description for a custom module using the [metatag module](http://drupal.org/project/metatag).

I tried this without success:

```
function mycustommodule_metatag_metatags_view_alter(&$output, $instance) {
  if ($instance == 'mycustom:entity') {
    $output['description']['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0] = array(
      array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#name' => 'desription',
        '#value' => $my_custom_description,
      ),
      'description',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: See this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13571/how-to-add-custom-metatags-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly altering the metatag, you might want to look into creating a custom token: [As described in this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488)

This will give you more freedom and flexibility. Then you can just use that custom token in the backend of metatags and configure it for content types that you like.

`/admin/config/search/metatags`
[image: metatag page]

If you however, still prefer to use the hook in the op, don't forget that those are cached, you will need to clear all caches before it might appear.